# dense matrix vs sparse matrix in python

Tags: python, performance, matrix, sparse-matrix

I'm comparing in python the reading time of a row of a matrix, taken first in dense and then in sparse format.

The "extraction" of a row from a dense matrix costs around 3.6e-05 seconds

For the sparse format I tried both csr_mtrix and lil_matrix, but both for the row-reading spent around 1-e04 seconds

I would expect the sparse format to give the best performance, can anyone help me understand this ?

Comment: What do you mean "extraction" of a row? What **exactly** are you doing? Also, why do you expect a sparse matrix to give the best performance when it comes to *speed*? Sparse matrices are optimized for their *memory utilization*. Speed/memory is a common trade-off

Comment: For extraction I mean row = M[i,:], or row = M.getrow(i)if it is sparse.
I would expect it to be better, at least intuitive, because in sparse format, I do not need to actually read all the row  but only the nonzero values.
Maybe I had to specify that it is a sparse matrix the one I had, so a lot of zeros

Comment: Dense arrays are memory-contiguous. Some sparse arrays are as well (i.e. `csr`). `lil` arrays are not and each value in a row requires a different random access. This obviously leads to exceptionally poor performance for most access and math operations.

Answer (score 2):

`arr[i,:]` for a dense array produces a `view`, so its execution time is independent of `arr.shape`.  If you don't understand the distinction between `view` and `copy`, you need to do more reading about `numpy` basics.

`csr` and `lil` formats allow indexing that looks a lot like `ndarray's`, but there are key differences.  For the most part the concept of a `view` does not apply.  There is one exception.  `M.getrowview(i)` takes advantage of the unique data structure of a `lil` to produce a `view`. (Read its doc and code)

Some indexing of a `csr` format actually uses matrix multiplication, using a specially constructed 'extractor' matrix.

In all cases where sparse indexing produces sparse matrix, actually constructing the new matrix from the data takes time.  Sparse does not use compiled code nearly as much as `numpy`.  It's strong point, relative to `numpy` is matrix multiplication of matrices that are 10% sparse (or smaller).

In the simplest format (to understand), `coo`, each nonzero element is represented by 3 values - data, row, col.  Those are stored in 3 1d arrays.  So it has to have a sparsity of less than 30% to even break even with respect to memory use.  `coo` does not implement indexing.